# Use fetch and asyncData together

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js, hook, asyncdata

I've a doubt..

In my Nuxt static project pages (Nuxt version => 2.12), I need to be fast with data recuperation.

#### The assumption:

With asyncData, the objective of speed is checked, because with asyncData I can get data during the component render. But this project has 3 different possible API calls, as many as the languages that I set and, when I select one language the value is saved in the Vuex store.

At the same time of this process, the language value is also saved on local storage, so, if I use only asyncData, when the page is refreshed the API call will not be the right call with the saved language (asyncData can't access the local storage).

Here, the fetch hook enters into the game, with the watch set on the state language value of the store, it can trigger the fetch and get the right data. Moreover, even when the page is refreshed, the fetch hook, being able to read the values of the local storage, can do its work great.

So why don't I use only the fetch hook? Because the fetch is slower than asyncData.

#### The questions:

Is the use of both fetch and asyncData an anti-pattern?

Is there a better way?

Here my code:

```js
export default {
  asyncData (context) {
    const slug = (context.route.path === '/' || context.route.path === '') ? '/home' : context.route.path
    return context.app.$storyapi
      .get(`cdn/stories${slug}`, {
        language: context.store.state.language.language
      }).then((res) => {
        return res.data
      }).catch((res) => {
        context.$errorMessage(res.response,
          'Sorry but this content doesn\'t extist', `Sorry, but the content called: "${context.route.name}" has a problem or doesn't exist`
        )
      })
  },
  data () {
    return {
      story: {
        content: {}
      }
    }
  },
  async fetch () {
    const slug = (this.$route.path === '/' || this.$route.path === '') ? '/home' : this.$route.path
    const { data } = await this.$storyapi.get(`cdn/stories${slug}`, {
      language: this.$store.state.language.language
    })
    this.story = data.story
  },
  watch: {
    '$store.state.language.language': '$fetch'
  }
}
```

Just to complete the information I would like to further say that the code works well, the matter is concerning the best practice.

Comment: `asyncData` can read your localstorage. You access the language in `asyncData` by accessing the VUEX store. So is it undefined there? Maybe the problem lies in the code, which fills the VUEX store from the localstorage

Comment: I access the store from asyncData from the context:
language: context.store.state.language. However, when I refresh the page, the state of the language in the store, which I saved in the local storage and which I need to make the right API call, is initialized, i.e. context.store.state.language.language = "" instead of context.store.state.language.language = "es".

Comment: Can you add the code, where you fill the language store value from the local storage?

Comment: I use a library: vuex-persistedstate. I create a nuxt plugin:

import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

export default ({ store }) => {
  createPersistedState({
    key: 'vuex',
    paths: ['language']
  })(store)
}

so, at each refresh I don't lose my value

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since when `fetch()` is slower than `asyncData()`?
Also, if you really need to re-run something you can totally [use `await this.$nuxt.refresh()`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/context-helpers#refreshing-page-data).
You could probably run both of those but they can kinda make the same thing, so it's kinda a duplication and I'd recommend to choose only one.

I'm not sure how it being located in localStorage is an issue but you could probably use one of the available packages to have an universal storage of this data, like this one: https://github.com/unjs/unstorage
If not, cookies should be enough too (available both on server and client).

Comment: Hi kissu.. by "slower" I mean that in Nuxt's lifecycle, fetch comes later. So, giving an example, if I have to dynamically populate the title in the head of a page, using fetch, it might show undefined until the fetchState.pending becomes false.

Comment: If you look at the lifecyle here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#lifecycle You notice that you do have `asyncData` -> `beforeCreate` -> `created` -> `fetch`. Creating an instance is not that heavy (it's not a `mounted`), and if the `beforeCreate` is empty, this should not matter that much. Even if all of those are doing things, it's not 2 steps during the cycle that will be significantly slow down your page: comparing few ms (or lower) and a whole API fetch is laughable. Even fetching the SSL certificate may take a longer time than 2 steps of the cycle. Don't overthink it.

Comment: Also, this kind of optimization is super fine-grained and probably overkill. If you want to have the best of the best in terms of performance, you won't even use Nuxt or any framework at all but just ship super low level code, like binary. If you're working at Amazon, it may be noticeable to grasp a few ms here and there, but this is probably not your case (I assume) so yeah, write some simple and writable code and you should be good IMO! @DanieleFalchetti

Comment: Well yes, I work at Amazon. No, just kidding. Anyway, you're right, I am a perfectionist but the fact is I want to push the tools I use to the max. With Nuxt this is very possible, given the cool framework that it is. Anyway I'll try to make one or the other hook effective, I don't know which one yet, but what is certain is that there will be only one left. Thanks a lot kissu.